# How to install icons on Ubuntu 14.04 using gnome shell?

Tags: gnome, icons

I have installed gnome-shell 3.10 and gnome-desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have found icon pack that I want to use, but there is to many how to's and none of them works. I have downloaded icon pack from [here](http://the-ilife.com/post/127), created .icons directory within my home directory, installed gnome-tweak tool and user theme extension logout-login, even restarted machine, but icon package is still not shown in "Icons" drop down menu. Global dark theme is turned OFF. Permissions are set as for the theme directory and owner is user. Any clue?

Comment: "I have downloaded icon pack from here, created .icons directory within my home directory" so you did not extract the icon them from the zip file, I'm guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the icon theme to:

`usr/share/icons`

where folder (and subfolders) have these permissions:

[image]

Comment: I have even copied to /usr/share/icons, permissions were good, all 0755, but problem was that directory with assets was nested inside name-master directory.

Comment: So you just had to copy it "out" right ?